# Usage of Socket and HTTP request

Tags: android, django, sockets, http, tcp

I am practicing an Android app, and want to ask for some pointers on implementing this feature:

When both user A and B press and hold a button on their phones at the same time, they can receive an information from server together. 

For example, while A press and hold a button on screen, B also press the button on B's phone, server will recognize the match and response with a "match" string. If after user A finished press the button, B start press and hold, the server won't recognize the match.

I want to ask what will be a good approach to implement this functionality on both mobile side and sever side. Should I send an regular HTTP request and let the server hang the response until match or timeout? or will it be a better approach to use Socket in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can handle it with HTTP requests or with sockets.

You need to consider the network latency, specially with HTTP. Maybe both users press the button each for 3 seconds, but B starts pressing at time=2s. If your network latency is 1+ seconds then there's no match.

With sockets you would have a much better performance latency wise. Needless to say the hardest part would be programming the server to which both devices connect.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to choose from both, I think the most suitable solution for this would be `Sockets` as far as perfomance goes. You simply declare one socket and you don't close it until needed. Probably the data transfer would be much lower than with HTTP requests.

I'd define an endless `Thread` which will send to the server the status of the button, i.e., a `boolean` value. The server would need to have a pool of sockets and handle them accordingly.

Another approach would be using [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), and I think this one is even better (though a bit more complex to implement, but probably you'll be thankful after implementing it). This way you simply send to the server the status changes, so you can afford this simply by implementing `onClickListener()` on the button and send the status change. The data transferred using this approach is really low, so the performance is even better. If you're interested in this approach, I recommend reading [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/pubsub_messaging).